# Trigger Inserting Large Amount of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a trigger that every new insert on the table, inserts some info in another table called AUDLOG.
The SQL is very straightforward:

```
INSERT AUDLOG( ID,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7 )
(
  SELECT
  ID,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  GETDATE(),
  0,
  CAST( SYSTEM_USER AS VARCHAR(50) ), 
  'INSERTED',
  FROM INSERTED
)
```

The problem is sometimes I have to make a big amount of insert at once (about 350k new rows) and this become very slow and locks my entire database. 
I tought doing this trigger using cursor, or by batches of 10k maybe. 
What's the best strategy for this? The focus should be not freezes the database and performance, if possible to both at same time.

Comment: A trigger executes in the context of the transaction that fired the trigger so batching won't help. Are there indexes on the AUDLOG table that might be contributing to the cost?

Comment: How are you currently inserting the rows?

Comment: Best way is really find a time where you can run this insert as a job outside of normal production hours. Disable the trigger and Indexes, INSERT then rebuild INDEX, Re enable triggers.

Comment: If you can get away with it, I'd agree with Isaiah3015, if not, a hybrid of Isiah and Dan's would probably be your best bet (e.g. if insertedCount > (put a magic number here), drop AUDLOG index, insert, recreate... otherwise insert).